# Swagger doesn't show int? as nullable

Tags: c#, swagger, oas3

If I have a property:

```
public int? Test { get; set; }
```

The correspoding swagger defination is:

```
test    integer($int32)
        nullable: true
```

However, when I add `[Required]` attribute to it:

```
[Required]
public int? Test { get; set; }
```

My swagger defination is:

```
test*   integer($int32)
```

Why is it no longer nullable?

Comment: because you've said its 'required', hence can't be null...

Comment: @cjb110 That is not true, the property is required to be supplied. The supplied value can be null or int.

Comment: The system does not make a distinction between null and not specified. Not specified is a specific feature that can happen in JSON but the RequiredAttribute does not know anything about JSON. It a more common attribute working on classes. Therefore required means there must be a value in this property different from null. And i assume  Swashbuckle that presumably generated your Swagger Definition knows that and created the proper description fitting to the behavior of that attribute.

Comment: To be precise, OpenAPI doesn't distinguish between `null` and "not specified".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[Reqiured]` attribute you are using forces the value, to not be `null`.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-8.0%5D):

> The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.